# Closed Captions resolving error System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

So, I'm trying to implement closed captions support to my UWP video player (using MediaElement), I've followed this [example](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/VideoPlayback/cs/Scenario4_DisplayingOutOfBandClosedCaptions.xaml.cs) to do so.

I'm getting an error when resolving it called `"Error resolving track due to error NetworkError System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"`

I do it like this: I open a file using filepicker and then get the `SRT` of the video that was picked. After that I show it. Unfortunately, nothing appears.

Here is my `OpenButton` function:

```
 private async void BtnOpenMedia_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FileOpenPicker filePicker = new FileOpenPicker();
        filePicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        filePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.VideosLibrary;
        filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp4");
        filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wmv");
        filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mpg");
        filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mpeg");
        filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");

        StorageFile storageFile = await filePicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

        if (storageFile != null && mElement != null)
        {
            string strSource = Path.GetDirectoryName(storageFile.Path) + @"\" + storageFile.DisplayName + ".srt";

            var mediaSource = MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(storageFile);

            var ttsStream = TimedTextSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri(strSource));

            ttsStream.Resolved += TtsStream_Resolved;

            mediaSource.ExternalTimedTextSources.Add(ttsStream);

            var mediaPlayback = new MediaPlaybackItem(mediaSource);

            mElement.SetPlaybackSource(mediaPlayback);
        }
    }
```

Here is my resolve function:

```
private void TtsStream_Resolved(TimedTextSource sender, TimedTextSourceResolveResultEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Error != null)
        {
            var ignoreAwaitWarning = Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
            {
                var msg = new MessageDialog("Error resolving track " + " due to error " + args.Error.ErrorCode + "  " + args.Error.ExtendedError);
                await msg.ShowAsync();
            });
            return;
        }
    }
```

P.S: Also, I don't know if this is duplicated or not, that's why I'm adding it in this but I've done my research and found nothing. How to preview frames of MediaElement ? For example like YouTube you can preview thumbnails in the slider, I don't know how to achieve that, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used a `FileOpenPicker` to select the Video file, but use a Path to access the .srt file. The .srt file is also in the Video file's folder. I reproduced your problem here:

[image]

The error message is clear, you have no access to this file, this file indicates the .srt file, so the problem is where did you store this .srt file. Just have a test, seems `TimedTextSource.CreateFromUri(Uri) | createFromUri(Uri) method` does not support to access the files in the local machine, but you can use [TimedTextSource.CreateFromStream(IRandomAccessStream) | createFromStream(IRandomAccessStream) method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.media.core.timedtextsource.createfromstream.aspx) for example like this:

```
if (storageFile != null && mElement != null)
{
    //string strSource = Path.GetDirectoryName(storageFile.Path) + @"\" + storageFile.DisplayName + ".srt";
    var fileSource = await KnownFolders.VideosLibrary.GetFileAsync(storageFile.DisplayName + ".srt");
    IRandomAccessStream strSource = await fileSource.OpenReadAsync();

    var mediaSource = MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(storageFile);
    //var ttsStream = TimedTextSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri(strSource));
    var ttsStream = TimedTextSource.CreateFromStream(strSource);

    ttsStream.Resolved += TtsStream_Resolved;

    mediaSource.ExternalTimedTextSources.Add(ttsStream);

    var mediaPlayback = new MediaPlaybackItem(mediaSource);

    mediaPlayback.TimedMetadataTracksChanged += (sender1, args) =>
    {
        mediaPlayback.TimedMetadataTracks.SetPresentationMode(0, TimedMetadataTrackPresentationMode.PlatformPresented);
    };

    mElement.SetPlaybackSource(mediaPlayback);
}
```

When using this code, the .srt file and video file should in the Video lib and the capability "Videos Library" should be enabled in the manifest.

In an UWP app, you can only access the files in known folder like picture lib, music lib and video lib and doc lib or local folder of your app, if your video is not in these folders, you should also handle the exception when access is denied in this scenario.

> How to preview frames of MediaElement ? For example like YouTube you can preview thumbnails in the slider.

For this question, I can't find any ready-made sample for you, but I think the scenario 4 of official [Media editing sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/MediaEditing) can be a direction, it shows a overlay layer on `MediaElement`, maybe you can set the "baseVideoFile" and the "overlayVideoFile" with the same source. The problem is when and where to show this overlay layer, it's related to the transport control of `MediaElement`. This is for now just a mind, you can have a try.

Comment: Thank you! It is solved by your fix! By the way, why doesn't Microsoft say in their sample that you can't access files from path? Like literally, I didn't even know that I can't. Is there any work around to access it without being in video library? Because you know, If I opened a movie in another path, the player should be able to find it without the user's help. Is there a way to do that? And thanks for the second part, I'll see what I can do in it !

Comment: @AhmedSabry, I just discussed with my colleague, the doc is unclear now and this is possible a bug, not sure, but we need to investigate on it further. UWP apps are work in sand box, there is no way to access those folders which can not be access in the code behind unless using filepicker to let user handle this.

Comment: Okay, I've started using FilePicker to add captions, but how can I set captions to MediaElement without touching the mediaplayback source? 

Like, I'm playing a video. Then I want to assign to this video an closed caption using FilePicker (I already chose the video before), It seems there isn't a way to set ExternalTimedTextSources without having to SetPlaybackSource ..

Comment: @AhmedSabry, yes, so I suggested to handle the exception (for example show a message to user) if the srt file is not in the available folder.